# ng-controller not working in body element

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have started learning Angular.js and this is my first activity. It all starts fine but when I add ng-controller to body element It does not work. I'm stuck here. Can you tell me what is the problem here?

```
<html ng-app="helloWorldApp">

<head>
    <title>Angular Fundamentals</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body ng-controller="firstController">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>AngularFundamentals</h1>
      <h2> {{'Hello World from Angular'}}</h2>
    </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var helloWorldApp = angular.module('helloWorldApp',[]);
    helloWorldApp.controller('firstController',[ '$scope', function(scope){
      $scope.appName =" An App Name";

    }]);
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello! Do you get any error? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: What do you mean it does not work?

Comment: Typo: `function(scope)` should be `function($scope)`.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply I actually missed that $ sign and also didn't write appName in {{}}. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
 <h2>{{appName}}</h2>
```

**DEMO**

```js
  var helloWorldApp = angular.module('helloWorldApp',[]);
 helloWorldApp.controller('firstController',['$scope', function($scope){
      $scope.appName =" An App Name";

 }]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="helloWorldApp">
<head>
<body ng-controller="firstController">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>AngularFundamentals</h1>
      <h2> {{appName}}</h2>
    </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan